# EJS logic works, but html isn't showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working on a timer using Express.js and EJS. I'm trying to update the html dynamically but i don't get anything displayed. But i get the console.log in my cli.

```html
<div id="countdown">
                    <% setInterval(function(){ %>
                        <% var now = new Date().getTime(); %>
                        <% var distance = expiration - now; %>
                        <% var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); %>
                        <% var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000); %>
                        <% if (distance > 0 ) { %>
                            <% console.log(minutes + ':' + seconds) %>
                            <p>This isn't showing</p>
                        <% } else { %>
                            <% console.log('expired') %>
                            <p>This isn't showing</p>
                        <% }; %> 
                    <% }, 1000); %>
                </div>
```

[CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrzMJ.png)
Am i missing something obvious?

I have other dynamic tags as `<h2>Send <%= displayAmount %> to:</h2>` 
but they aren't working inside the conditional.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if this is happening because express is barfing at the concept of interleaving HTML with a timer.  Might want to use DOM calls to update the content of your countdown div instead of trying to emit HTML

Comment: I’ll check into this. What gets my attention is the fact that the logs are working but html is ghosting.

Comment: Your logs are valid JavaScript being emitted at page render by express that are being executed at some time in the future - no problem there.  The `p` tags are being theoretically being emitted at some stage in the future ... with probably no context at all.  There's little wonder they aren't being displayed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JavaScript keeps running, as you have programmed it to do, but the page is not re-rendering, because it is only told to render once.

You would have to write another JavaScript function that will re-render the DOM every iteration.

Something like:

```
let myDiv = document.getElementById('countdown');

// Delete previously added elements
while (myDiv.firstChild) {
  myDiv.removeChild(myDiv.firstChild);
}

// Create a <p>
let p = document.createElement('p');

// Create your text
let text = document.createTextNode(`${minutes}:${seconds}`);
// OR:
let text = document.createTextNode('Expired');

// Append the text to <p>
p.appendChild(text);

// Append the <p> to div
myDiv.appendChild(p);
```